# If $\mathbb{E}(|X_1|)=\infty$ then a.s. $X_n/n$ does not tend to 0.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

Let $(X_n)_{n \geq 1}$ be i.i.d. real random variables. Then my prof. wrote: „If $\mathbb{E}(|X_1|)=\infty$ then a.s. $X_n/n$ does not tend to 0“

I’m not so comfortable with probability notation so far so I‘m using the notation from measure theory. I interpret the statement as:

$$
\mathbb{E}(|X_1|)= \infty \Rightarrow  \mathbb{P}(\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} X_n/n = 0) = 0
$$
Is this correct so far? Then I tried to prove it:

\begin{equation}
        \infty = \mathbb{E}(|X_n|)= \int_{0}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(|X_1| \geq t) \ dt = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int_{n}^{n+1} \mathbb{P}(|X_n|/ \geq t) \ dt \leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  \mathbb{P}(|X_n| \geq n)
    \end{equation}
Since the $|X_n|$ are still i.i.d. by the second Borel-Cantelli Lemma we get:
\begin{equation}
    \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } \mathbb{P}\left( \{\omega \ : \ |X_n|\geq n\}\right)=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } \mathbb{P}\left( \bigcup_{m=n}^{\infty} \{\omega \ : \ |X_m|\geq m\}\right) =\mathbb{P}\left(\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{m=n}^{\infty} \{\omega \ : \ |X_m|\geq m\}\right) = 1
\end{equation}
Thus:
\begin{equation}
    \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } \mathbb{P}\left( \{\omega \ : \ |X_n|/n\geq 1\}\right) = 1
\end{equation}
Hence for all $\varepsilon > 0$ there is a $N$ s.t. for all $n > N$ we have: $|\mathbb{P}\left( \{\omega \ : \ |X_n|/n\geq 1\}\right) - 1|< \varepsilon$
i.e. $|\mathbb{P}\left( \{\omega \ : \ |X_n|/n = 0\} \right) | \leq |\mathbb{P}\left( \{\omega \ : \ |X_n|/n < 1\} \right) |< \varepsilon$, i.e.

\begin{equation}
      \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } \mathbb{P}\left( \{\omega \ : \ |X_n|/n = 0\}\right) = 0
\end{equation}

But I‘m still not at:
$$
\mathbb{P}(\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} X_n/n = 0) = 0
$$

Could someone show me how to get there, or show me a faster way? Thank you!:)

Comment: I'm not sure but you have showed that $\Bbb{P}(|X_m|\geq m ~\text{i.o})=1$ so almost surly infinitely often $|X_m|\geq m$. But wouldn't this imply that $\Bbb{P}(\lim_{m\rightarrow \infty} |X_m|/m=0)=0$. Maybe there is someone who can help us.

Comment: Yes if I knew that I‘d be done, but right now I can’t see why:
$ \mathbb{P}(\lim \sup_{m \rightarrow \infty} \{\omega : |X_m| \geq m\})=1 \Rightarrow \mathbb{P}(\{\omega : \lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} |X_m|/m=0 \})=0$

Comment: $|X_m|/m \to 0$ imples $\lim \sup (|X_m|\geq m)$ false. Entirely trivial.

Comment: Could you maybe elaborate?

Comment: @geetha290krm: but how does your remark imply that you can move the limit in the penultimate equation (where it is a limit of a sequence of events) inside $\Bbb{P}$ to get the final equation, where the limit is a limit of a sequence of real numbers?

Comment: @RobArthan If $P(B)=1$ and $A \subseteq B^{c}$ then $P(A)=0$.

Comment: @geetha290krm: it would be very helpful if you were kind enough to write up an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you’re overthinking this a little. You’ve already done the hard part above! You just need to put it together.

As you observed, using BC2, you can establish:

$$\mathbb{P}[X_n \geq n \text{ infinitely often}] = 1$$

Now we simply play with our probability space. First, we observe:

$$\{ \omega : X_n \geq n \text{ infinitely often}\} = \{ \omega : \limsup_n \frac{X_n}{n} \geq 1\}$$

Second, that:

$$\{\omega : \lim_n \frac{X_n}{n} = 0 \} \subseteq \{ \omega : \limsup_n \frac{X_n}{n} < 1\} = \Omega \setminus \{ \omega : \limsup_n \frac{X_n}{n} \geq 1\} $$

It then easily follows from the second observation that:
$$\mathbb{P}[\lim_n \frac{X_n}{n} = 0] \leq 1 - \mathbb{P}[\limsup_n \frac{X_n}{n} \geq 1]$$
But we already showed that $$\mathbb{P}[\limsup_n \frac{X_n}{n} \geq 1] = \mathbb{P} [X_n \geq n \text{ infinitely often}] = 1$$

This proves the desired result.

Comment: Thank you for your answer:) I‘m just a bit confused because B.C.2 makes a statement about the measure of the set $\lim \sup_{n\rightarrow \infty}\{\omega : X_n(\omega)/n \geq 1\}$ is this really the same set as the one in your proof, i.e. $\{\omega : \lim \sup_{n\rightarrow \infty} X_n(\omega)/n \geq 1\} $

Comment: Yeah they’re the same set. Notice that if $p \in \limsup_n \{\omega : X_n(\omega)/n \geq 1\}$ if and only if $p$ is in $\{\omega : X_n(\omega)/n \geq 1\}$ for infinitely many $n$. This, respectively, is true if and only if $\limsup_n X_n(p)/n \geq 1$ as a sequence of real numbers.

Comment: @HenryT. It's important to realize that for a sequence of sets $A_{n}$, you have $\limsup\mathbf{1}_{A_{n}}=\mathbf{1}_{\lim\sup A_{n}}$ . i.e. $\omega \in \lim\sup A_{n}$ iff $\omega\in A_{n}$ for infinitely many $n$ iff $\mathbf{1}_{A_{n}}(\omega)=1$ infinitely often.